# При установке Android Studio 3 нет установки sdk

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

До этого стояла старая версия. Удалила, подчистила все следы в C:\Users...
Глупый вопрос, наверное, но что делать?

Comment: После установки Android Studio, можно установить SDK уже из интерфейса IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно, `SDK` находится по пути `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`.

И обновлять версию AS можно внутри самой среды.

P.S. На данный момент доступна стабильная версия AS 3.0.1

Comment: чтобы она там находилась, ее надо туда поставить. Но при установке студии 3.0.1 нет предложения поставить sdk. Я думаю, надо что-то еще подчистить, чтобы программа убедилась в отсутствии sdk на компе и предложила поставить. но что - я не знаю.

Comment: Заходите в настройки - System Setting - Android SDK - Android SDK Location. Выберите папку, где установлена Android SDK. В ином случае предложит установить SDK.